# Joining / Merging asynchronous related tables

Tags: excel, vba

**Goal**

I need help to find the most effective way to perform the following transformation in excel. When referring to 'effective way', I mean the simplest and most efficient method to successfully obtain the output I'm looking for.

**Problem**

For the sake of simplicity, I'll present you a dummy over-simplified example of the conceptual problem that, once solved, will allow me to accomplish what I need.

Let it be 2 tables.
Table 1 logs the Daily Average Sales per Employee every week. That value applies from every day from the `WeekStartingDate` to `WeekStartingDate + 4`.

[image: Table1]

Table 2 logs to which Team each Employee is allocated. Table 2 is (manually) updated ad-hoc whenever an Employee changes Team. Therefore, Table 2 keeps track of each Employee's Team by setting a 'time frame' during which that table entry is valid.

[image: Table2]

I want to combine both tables to have a log of Average Daily Sales per Employee per Team, such as depicted below. Notice the 'time frames' on the output table corresponded to the minimum periods in which there wasn't a change neither in Table1ID (i.e. in week) and in Employee's Team.

[image: Table3]

**Rules**

Macros/ using VBA is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like combine two tables. For this first convert both data ranges into Tables and any where create a new table structure.

Since it's copy and paste only so following code will help you.

Sub CombineTables()

Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

Set Rng1= ThisWorkbook.Names("Tab1").RefersToRange

Set Rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Names("Tab2").RefersToRange

ThisWorkbook.Connections(1).Refresh

Rng1.Copy
Sheet1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Rng2.Copy

Sheet1. Range("A1").Offset(Rng1.Rows.Count, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

End Sub

Comment: I don't quite understand how does your solution cross-checks the time frames. Consider employee B during the week starting on 08-01-2017: this employee changes from Team X to Team Y on 11-01-2017 and thus the output table shall break into a new row (as depicted on my post). Does your solution accomplish that? Which line in the code does that? Thanks